# What are the economic effects of an electricity shutdown that lasts weeks in big city?

Tags: society, economy, government, cities

How this affects the economy of the big tech industries like factories and the media like radio stations and television?
What are the effects that this brings in the life of normal people?

Comment: I'm afraid you're failing what we call the book test. This concept and its effects could be the premise for an entire book, or possibly series of books, without covering the full range of situations it generates. As such it's too broad for us to answer within this format.

Comment: To broad a question. The effects would be myriad and utter chaos. I assume you mean modern day?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand our community and its standards. Your question as written now is quite broad, and thus likely to be closed. Daily life is different for every citizen and organization, in Tokyo there are several million people and a similar number of organizations. We cannot answer case by case. Please narrow it down to a manageable size,

Comment: To rephrase the other comments, this is a myriad of questions rolled into one.  Try breaking it down and ask *one* of those questions at a time (you can post multiple questions simultaneously if needed, just not in the same "question" post).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I just edited the question to a specific one.

Comment: Your edit is still far to broad. Your big fishes is far to diverse to answer. A factory owner is hit far harder then someone who is active in the service industry. I suggest you start with checking what services are impacted and how long it takes for them to become a problem, like garbage collection and traffic lights etc. A classroom can be run somewhat effective with a backup generator and some books, a movie theater less so...

Comment: Too broad to answer as presently written. Also, you should address the feasibility of this: no major city has just one source of power, to my understanding, but uses electricity from multiple sources. A disaster that could take out _all_ of those at once is very difficult to imagine (unless it entails the city being flattened, which I suspect is not your intent). And moreover, you want this city to be without power for weeks? In that kind of scenario, you'll have a massive response within hours, and power will be back within days. You're going to need a very good explanation for _weeks_.

Comment: You do understand that if electric power is not available in a big city for three weeks then most of its inhabitants will have to flee elsewhere, or else die? Without electric power it is not only the economic activity which stops, it's also that there is no *water*. Not to mention that without public illumination at night, life in many big cities will decay into a violent hell of plunder and riots...

Comment: I suggest you look at the effects of major blackouts on cities, for example from hurricanes. It is common to have major food spoilage, water shortages, gas shortages. How much of this actually comes from the electricity vs other factors is up for debate, but it is probably a case study for what you are looking for. I think major companies are generally unaffected, because of backup power sources, though how long the blackout lasts may be a factor.

Comment: This comments really help me. Thank you all. I'll definitely do research on historical events.

Comment: [Based on the much-studied 1977 New York City blackout, ICF Consulting estimated the total economic cost of the August 2003 blackout to be between \$7 and \$10 billion.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwial7y-m7ngAhVQyYMKHZmLDLAQFjABegQIBxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Felcon.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2FEconomic20Impacts20of20August20200320Blackout1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0_36BtJvWqUyXx7i6Dd1jx)  HOWEVER, every city's cost will be unique based on the industry of that city.  Even this estimate has a 30% error factor.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a bigger demand for fuel for generators. Most big companies would have generators already. Those that didn't would purchase them. Disruption apart from that would not be too great for core work. I live on a cyclone prone island, loss of mains power is a bit disruptive and gives a chance for a bit of drama, but not a huge problem.

I actually have to go out and turn my generator on, but most of the big buildings don't, their generators automatically flick on when the mains goes down.

Comment: Don't forget food would also spoil because of refrigeration (and their lack of power), tele-communication might stop working with cell towers going offline because of lack of power, and phones running out of battery, etc etc.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper generators take care of that. Never heard of a Telco without emergency power sources.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper great idea

Comment: I disagree that everyone in a city is going to keep generators running around the clock, but that is up for debate. Part of the question does say "normal people"

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper you're right, I didn't bother with that bit because I'd need to write a book and it's locale specific as issues would vary, (heating wouldn't be an issue in the tropics), it would inconvenience many normal people and households, probably not as much as you think though, but heating, refrigeration etc,. But the vast majority of people handle it fine if you've ever seen this sort of situation. In fact they socialise a lot more in positive ways as they help each other and most people don't really store all that much perishable food in their houses and can always give it away.

Comment: Well I live in Florida where hurricanes regularly cause blackouts for days or weeks. Food spoilage and gas shortages (generators have to run on something) are very common. Traffic congestion for gas is common. Big companies like you say are not usually affected, because I have actually gone to work while my entire neighborhood has been powerless. I think the OPs question can be answered by looking at what happens when a hurricane causes an extended blackout.

Comment: Unsure where Florida is, but if hurricanes are common why are they not prepared for them? Would expect they'd have more brains there... we have cyclones, so normal assets for anyone who can afford them are emergency supplies, generator and water tank. Fuel availability would be the only issue and we'd ration that if we had to and supplement by sip[honing from vehicles... just common sense stuff. We get frequent blackouts just because our electric power ministry is useless.

Comment: Just telling you what actually happens. Florida https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I could have looked it up... but if I start looking up every place in the World someone mentions I'd overload myself with info that is irrelevant to me.... no offence

Comment: Yeah I feel like I am wasting my time too. Good luck.